# checking OS details in ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: system-monitor

I have just installed ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS in my computer. when i am triying to see the details about my system then it shows me ubuntu 14.04 LTS instead of ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. why the details not shown "ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS"?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, type following command to print distribution-specific information :

```
lsb_release -a
```

**In Ubuntu 14.04.1, Point releases are just security updates up to date.**